# Are there polynomial time reductions where the corresponding witnesses can't be translated in polynomial time?

Tags: np-complete

At the heart of NP-completeness is the idea that one can reduce *instances* of any problem in NP to, for example, 3-SAT. But this definition doesn't require that it must be possible to convert witnesses for yes-instances in polynomial time also. Does this fact follow regardless?
I'm looking at this in particular from the point of view of zero-knowledge proofs. Here the existence of computationally zero-knowledge proofs for all problems in NP is demonstrated by showing that 3-colorability has such proofs. But the guarantee that I can translate problems - or "conjectures" - in polynomial time is useless. I need to be able to translate witnesses - or "proofs". How is the possibility of this assured?

Answer (score 1):

The proof of the Cook-Levin theorem shows that any problem in NP can be reduced to SAT in such a way that witnesses to the original problem can be converted efficiently to satisfying assignments of the resulting SAT instance. The proof of the NP-completeness of 3-colorability goes via a series of reductions, each of which also has this property.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I think that works for zero-knowledge proofs. I'm still curious about the title question though.

Comment: The usual rule is one question per post.

Comment: Well it is the title question...

Comment: Your post contains two questions. I answered one of them. You'll to ask the other one separately, editing this post so that it includes a single question.